# how to combine or join file with Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, ruby-on-rails-3.1, plupload

I using [jquery file upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) . In path [Chunked file uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads) when the file was chunk (or cut) to smaller files . It was combine in client or I must combine it in my controller . And how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps to build up your google skills:

[rails chunked file uploads](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki)

Comment: IN document I not understand, how it work ? should I combine it in my controller, shouldn 't I? oR It auto combine for me ?

Comment: Thanks, Google is the best :D